# Angular Want to modify ngIf value on HTML by CSS depending upon Mobile vs desktop

Tags: css, angular

I have a Angular component in which i have defined

In Component

```
toggle: boolean = true
toggleDetails()
{
  this.toggle = !this.toggle
}
```

In HTML

```
    <section *ngIf="!toggle">
```

This works perfectly in both desktop and mobile . but now i have to make by default value of toggle is false in case of mobile. So i am not sure how to achieve this. In searched a little and found that we have @media attribute in CSS but not sure how it can modify value of ngIf.

Comment: You can use the CDK library: https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function isMobile()
{
   return (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ); 
}
```

assign it to a parameter, and place that parameter in the *ngIf.

If you would like to modify your css depending on this parameter, you can use this:

```
<div [style]="'cssClassA': isMobileParameter"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use mediaQuery from @angular/flex-layout, which is an observable that watches de width of the browser windows and lets you act in consecuence.

I made and example which toggles a mat-button-group to a mat-menu depending on mediaQuery.

see it here : https://angular-rb5vmu.stackblitz.io , at the bottom "angular material responsive mat-button-toggle-group"